# organize data from a txt file

Tags: python

I am working with a txt file. I need to group the data based on the gene name, and identify how many non-zero values are in each column for the gene name.

What I have isn't allowing me to compare the characters before the underscore in order to check if these are in the same gene group.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need `pandas` in your life

Comment: Did you mean `split("_")`? Also, what is `number in range(8)`? There are only 4 characters before the underscore

Comment: What data organization are you trying to achieve? It's unclear from your question and the code in it.

Comment: Can add an overview of how the result will look like ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a dictionary to group by gene name, if you can afford to load the entire dataset into memory:

```
In [10]: import io

In [11]: from collections import defaultdict

In [12]: file = io.StringIO(s) # pretend I'm a file

In [13]: grouper = defaultdict(lambda: {'X1':[], 'X2':[], 'X3':[]})

In [14]: next(file) # skip header
Out[14]: 'Gene Name                  X1  X2  X3\n'

In [15]: for line in file:
    ...:     row = line.split()
    ...:     name, delim, seq  = row[0].partition('_')
    ...:     x1, x2, x3 = map(float, row[1:])
    ...:     columns = grouper[name]
    ...:     columns['X1'].append(x1)
    ...:     columns['X2'].append(x2)
    ...:     columns['X3'].append(x3)
    ...:

In [16]: grouper
Out[16]:
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'A1BG': {'X1': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              'X2': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              'X3': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]},
             'A1CF': {'X1': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              'X2': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.2],
              'X3': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.9]}})
```

You can then use the result like this:

```
In [17]: sum(x != 0 for x in grouper['A1BG']['X1'])
Out[17]: 0

In [18]: sum(x != 0 for x in grouper['A1BG']['X2'])
Out[18]: 0

In [19]: sum(x != 0 for x in grouper['A1BG']['X3'])
Out[19]: 0

In [20]: sum(x != 0 for x in grouper['A1CF']['X1'])
Out[20]: 0

In [21]: sum(x != 0 for x in grouper['A1CF']['X2'])
Out[21]: 1

In [22]: sum(x != 0 for x in grouper['A1CF']['X3'])
Out[22]: 1
```

**Edit** In case you want to use pandas:

```
In [28]: import pandas as pd

In [29]: file = io.StringIO(s) # pretend I'm a file

In [30]: df = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=[0], header=None, names=['Gene Name', 'X1','X2','X3'])

In [31]: df
Out[31]:
                    Gene Name  X1   X2   X3
0   A1BG_AAGAGCGCCTCGGTCCCAGC   0  0.0  0.0
1   A1BG_CAAGAGAAAGACCACGAGCA   0  0.0  0.0
2   A1BG_CACCTTCGAGCTGCTGCGCG   0  0.0  0.0
3   A1BG_CACTGGCGCCATCGAGAGCC   0  0.0  0.0
4   A1BG_GCTCGGGCTTGTCCACAGGA   0  0.0  0.0
5   A1BG_TGGACTTCCAGCTACGGCGC   0  0.0  0.0
6   A1CF_CCAAGCTATATCCTGTGCGC   0  0.0  0.0
7   A1CF_CGTGGCTATTTGGCATACAC   0  0.0  0.0
8   A1CF_GACATGGTATTGCAGTAGAC   0  0.0  0.0
9   A1CF_GAGTCATCGAGCAGCTGCCA   0  0.0  0.0
10  A1CF_GGTATACTCTCCTTGCAGCA   0  0.0  0.0
11  A1CF_GGTGCAGCATCCCAACCAGG   0  3.2  4.9

In [32]: df['name'] = df['Gene Name'].str.extract(r'(.*)_.*')

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
                    Gene Name  X1   X2   X3  name
0   A1BG_AAGAGCGCCTCGGTCCCAGC   0  0.0  0.0  A1BG
1   A1BG_CAAGAGAAAGACCACGAGCA   0  0.0  0.0  A1BG
2   A1BG_CACCTTCGAGCTGCTGCGCG   0  0.0  0.0  A1BG
3   A1BG_CACTGGCGCCATCGAGAGCC   0  0.0  0.0  A1BG
4   A1BG_GCTCGGGCTTGTCCACAGGA   0  0.0  0.0  A1BG
5   A1BG_TGGACTTCCAGCTACGGCGC   0  0.0  0.0  A1BG
6   A1CF_CCAAGCTATATCCTGTGCGC   0  0.0  0.0  A1CF
7   A1CF_CGTGGCTATTTGGCATACAC   0  0.0  0.0  A1CF
8   A1CF_GACATGGTATTGCAGTAGAC   0  0.0  0.0  A1CF
9   A1CF_GAGTCATCGAGCAGCTGCCA   0  0.0  0.0  A1CF
10  A1CF_GGTATACTCTCCTTGCAGCA   0  0.0  0.0  A1CF
11  A1CF_GGTGCAGCATCCCAACCAGG   0  3.2  4.9  A1CF

In [34]: template = "For gene {}, X1 count: {X1}, X2 count: {X2}, X3 count: {X3}"
    ...: for name, group in df.groupby('name'):
    ...:     print(template.format(name, **group.apply(np.count_nonzero)))
    ...:
For gene A1BG, X1 count: 0, X2 count: 0, X3 count: 0
For gene A1CF, X1 count: 0, X2 count: 1, X3 count: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` module along with `literal_eval` from `ast` module and `any()`, like this example:

```
from itertools import groupby
from ast import literal_eval as le
# I'm assuming your input file is called 'input.txt' 
# which contains the data you gave in your question
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = [k.split() for k in fp.read().splitlines()]

sub = {}
for k, v in groupby(sorted(data[1:], key= lambda x: x[0].split('_')[0]), lambda x: x[0].split('_')[0]):
    # Remove the 'x3' field if you don't need their results in your code
    _, x1, x2, x3 = list(zip(*list(v)))
    sub[k] = {'x1': x1, 'x2': x2, 'x3': x3}


for k in sub:
    for j in sub[k]:
        # if any values of the fields 'x1', 'x2' or 'x3' != 0 it will retuen 1
        # otherwise it will return 0
        print("{}:{}: {}".format(k, j, 1 if any(le(m) for m in sub[k][j]) else 0))
```

Output:

```
A1BG:x1: 0
A1BG:x3: 0
A1BG:x2: 0
A1CF:x1: 0
A1CF:x3: 1
A1CF:x2: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty:

```
>>> genes
[['A1BG_AAGAGCGCCTCGGTCCCAGC', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['A1BG_CAAGAGAAAGACCACGAGCA', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['A1BG_CACCTTCGAGCTGCTGCGCG', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['A1BG_CACTGGCGCCATCGAGAGCC', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['A1BG_GCTCGGGCTTGTCCACAGGA', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['A1BG_TGGACTTCCAGCTACGGCGC', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['A1CF_CCAAGCTATATCCTGTGCGC', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['A1CF_CGTGGCTATTTGGCATACAC', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['A1CF_GACATGGTATTGCAGTAGAC', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['A1CF_GAGTCATCGAGCAGCTGCCA', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['A1CF_GGTATACTCTCCTTGCAGCA', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['A1CF_GGTGCAGCATCCCAACCAGG', '0', '3.2', '4.9']]
>>> results = {}
>>> for gene in genes:
...     if(gene[0][0:4] in results and (float(gene[1])!=0.0 or float(gene[2])!=0.0 or float(gene[3])!=0.0)):
...        results[gene[0][0:4]]+=1
...     elif(gene[0][0:4] not in results and (float(gene[1])!=0.0 or float(gene[2])!=0.0 or float(gene[3])!=0.0)):
...        results[gene[0][0:4]]=1
...     else:
...        pass
>>> results
{'A1CF': 1}
```